# Walking along a moving train, we make 18 steps. Opposite: 11. How long is the train?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, relative-motion

> *A man walks in the same direction as a slowly moving train ($v_{man} > v_{train}$). He counts the train to be 18 steps long. Then he turns around and counts the train to be 11 steps long.*
>
> *(Suppose both man and train are moving at a constant speed; every step is the same length.)*
>
> *How long is the train?*

---

For some reason I always end up with two equations and four unknowns... I'd really appreciate a solution!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Key is to notice that your steps provide you with a unit length as well as a unit time. So, let's measure distance in $steps$ and time in $ticks$, with your speed being $1 \ step/tick$.

The length of the train is $x$ steps, and its speed is $v \ steps/tick$ ($v<1$).

It follows that

$$x \ + \ 18 \ v \ = \ 18 $$
$$x \ - \ 11 \ v \ = \ 11 $$

Adding 11 times the first equation to 18 times the second yields $29 x = 396$. The train is $396/29 \ steps$ long.

You also need to check if indeed $v < 1 \ step/tick$. Leave that to you to demonstrate.

Comment: Thank you. I've played with the idea of a step taking 1 second, just didn't follow through... (Accepted!)